# How do I make Git ignore a file by adding a comment inside that file, instead of adding the file to .gitignore?

Tags: git

Say I want to tell Git not to track any files that contain the string `//ignoreMe!`, how can I do that?

I specifically want to do this for files that are compiled artifacts of source files. I know how to do it with `.gitignore`, however, this doesn't scale well for a current project, where there are compiled files all over the place with many different file extensions, patterns, etc.

I can easily have the compilers add some content like `//GITIGNORE`, but it's harder to create rules that generalize well to match filenames in this particular project.

Comment: Did anybody advice you not to track files that are produced from compilation? If that hasn't happened yet, then let me be the first to tell you: `tracking compiled files from the source code of your project is a bad idea. don't do it unless your life depends on it`

Comment: *"Say I want to tell Git not to track any files that contain the string //ignoreMe!, how can I do that?"* -- add their names (and/or paths) to `.gitignore`. It's as simple as that. And yes, I have read the entire question. But the rest of it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @eftshift0 you've misread my question. I am trying NOT to track files produced from compilation.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there isn't a built-in way to do this in Git (probably do to the performance overhead this would require).

However, it should be possible to automate this.  First, we want to find the files that need to be ignored:

```
grep --files-with-match --recursive '// GITIGNORE' .
```

For each result, we can check if it is already ignored with `git check-ignore`.  If not, we add it to the local ignore file.

Putting this all together in a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

grep --files-with-match --recursive '// GITIGNORE' . | while read filename
  do
    if [ $(git check-ignore --quiet "$filename") -ne 0 ]
    then
      echo "$filename" >> .git/info/exclude
    fi
  done
```

If you add a build step to run that script at the end of the build, that should produce the result you desire.  Depending on how often the ignored filenames change, you may want to truncate `.git/info/exclude` from time to time.

(If you don't have access to `grep` or `bash`, it should be possible to do a similar thing with other tools on your system of choice.)

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler gives you enough control that you can compile arbitrary markers into the compiled output that aren't present in the source, but so little that you can't choose anything identifiable for the output files' names or locations? That's so obtuse I'm tempted to downvote in a feeble attempt to banish the thought, but it's too late, I'm going to have nightmares; and anyway I'd like to think sympathy for your possible plight would have stayed my hand.

No, Git's ignore processing checks only pathnames, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore build artifacts by folder.

If you setup doesn't build into an identifiable folder, change the configuration so it does.

Why not have a look at the [VisualStudio's gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore). Specifically:

```
# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
[Aa][Rr][Mm]/
[Aa][Rr][Mm]64/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
[Ll]og/
[Ll]ogs/
```

Comment: I ended up adding a gitignore per folder with compiled files for now.